# How to read the output window of Visual Studio in an efficient way?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, rebuild

Do you know any guideline or if you have mastered your own way of reading the output window of the VS after a failed build to gather the most important notes in a shortest time?

Comment: I speed things up by mainly ignoring it and using the Error List instead.

Comment: Setting MSBuild output verbosity to minimal (Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run) might help.

Comment: I set the font size really small so I can read everything important without abusing the scroll bar.

Answer (score 2):

well, may be the most efficient way to read build failures is the Error list window.

but may be it is useful to use the output window to track any exception occurred and handled implicitly, or to track any new loaded modules (assemblies).

or if you are using the build events, and there is a failure when running the dos commands, you can also see it in the output.

you can also write your own events to the output, using `Debug.Write("");`

and by the way, there are some frameworks (such as NHibernate) who log there events into the output window.